# Camel Split Parallel Processing aggregate messages

Tags: rest, concurrency, split, parallel-processing, apache-camel

Might look like a trivial problem but could not get it work unfortunately

This is the code

```
from("direct:START")
.process( (ex) -> {
   List<Integer> pages = IntStream.range(1,5).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
   ex.getOut().setBody( pages );
 })
.split(body())
.parallelProcessing()
.to("http://someurl?page=${body}");
 --> Get the collective body here
```

How to get this work!

Comment: You need to provide more information in order to allow people to help you: 1) what do you want the code to do? 2) what does the current code do?

Comment: @quant_dev Smaller question does not mean it has little information. The question is very precise and some one has already solved it.

Comment: This question is on hold. The number of lines does not decide the quality. The question is very clear in deed and straight to the point without unwanted stories . Any way I got my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Aggregator](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator.html) with `completionSize` Expression to aggregate splitted messages.

```
.split(body()).parallelProcessing().to("log:splitted_body_is_here")
.aggregate(constant(true), AggregationStrategies.groupedBody())
    .completionSize(exchangeProperty(Exchange.SPLIT_SIZE))
.to("log:aggregated_body_is_here")
```

If you are using older version of camel (2.20.x) **AggregationStrategies.groupedBody()** wont be available. You can use other method. I used a simple custom method to perform my aggregation.

The Code  changes to

```
.split(body()).parallelProcessing().to("log:splitted_body_is_here")
.aggregate(constant(true), (in,out) ->{
                if( in == null ){
                    return out;
                }
                else{
                    String body = in.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                    body = body + "," + out.getIn().getBody( String.class );
                    in.getOut().setBody( body );
                    return in;
                }
            })
    .completionSize(exchangeProperty(Exchange.SPLIT_SIZE))
.to("log:aggregated_body_is_here")
```

The above code, just assumes the body is a String/JSON and appends it by comma.

And it looks, you want to invoke endpoint with dynamic url in `to`. It is not supported, use `toD` instead.

Comment: Check out the big brain in brett :) Spot on! But I dont see a Class.method called AggregationStrategies.groupedBody(). Editing with the working code.

Comment: Thanks for edit, but `AggregationStrategies.groupedBody()` was not removed. It exists in [current versions](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/util/toolbox/AggregationStrategies.java). Maybe you are referring older versions, where it was named `AggregationStrategies.batch()` (renamed in [this commit](https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/a12d53f368c149e23c689f70f29f2a47b539829c#diff-e19247138ef2f2cc085900e7303654e3)), but the functionality was same. Or in which version you are missing it?

Comment: Oh god!. Am using old version. 2.20.x :( will upgrade right away. Thanks for the pointer. Edited the answer as well